# What tactical concerns should I keep in mind as I charge, shoot, or retreat?

Tags: necromunda

I'm playing a round of cooperative Necromunda, and am controlling a specific character on the field. Our party has just begun to engage with the enemy, and I'm looking for advice from experienced players on what to do for my next turn. My character's stat sheet is below:

[image: Character sheet]

---

The current layout of the board is below. My character is standing on the bridge at the top of the photo, blue hair clearly visible, her gun pointed at a rapidly approaching bad guy:
[image: View of the board]

---

The bad guy directly in front of me is described as armed with a sword and an autopistol, to be heavily armored, and to not appear to be either a leader or champion.

The other visible bad guy that I am concerned about, at the top of the tall tower on the right, is armed with a bolter.

There is an additional piece of cover one move to the left on the bridge I am standing on (it's a bit hard to tell in the photo, but the big metal panel to my left is a diagonally-aligned cover wall).

You can see my team scattered across the other upper bridge (2 models), in cover behind pillars on the ground (2 models), and advancing over the bridge at ground level (1 model).

I'd like to accomplish the following with my two actions, in priority order:

1. Not hang my teammates out to dry
2. Not do anything wildly ineffective
3. Either now or on a future turn, maximize my chances of taking out the bolter-equipped bad guy in the tower threatening my entire team
4. Survive

I am thinking about charging the enemy in front of me and stabbing them with my knife. I'm unclear if I am allowed to attack twice in one turn. I've also considered:

- Firing twice at the charging enemy with my stub gun, if I am allowed to do so
- Firing twice at the bolter-equipped figure at the top of the tower with my lasgun, if I am allowed to do so
- Retreating to the cover behind me and firing at the advancing enemy with my stub gun